# Where can I buy or acquire lock picks?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I am running low of lock picks. Those master locks really run through them. Apart from finding them as loot, where can I buy or acquire lock picks?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

*From the [Skyrim wiki](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Lockpicking_%28Skyrim%29):*

Lockpicks are easily obtained, as almost all merchants carry at least 1 of them. Some of the easier ways are:

- The Thieves Guild fence Tonilia carries around 30 picks for sale.
- The Khajiit trader outside Whiterun also carries 30 or more picks for sale.
- Babette in the Dark Brotherhood usually sells between 15 and 20 picks.
- General goods traders such as Belethor often carry 5 to 10 picks.
- Nearly all merchants, even food vendors will generally carry at least 1 lockpick in the miscellaneous category.
- Checking chests, bags and other storage units.
- Killing or pickpocketing bandits or humanoid monsters.
- The Skeleton Key. This lockpick is unique in that it will never break; the shaking animation will still occurr if you put too much pressure while in the wrong position, but the pick itself doesn't break, meaning that you can try an infinite number of times.

Comment: Pretty sure the Skeleton Key never plays the breaking animation.

Comment: @kotekzot it shows the pick vibrating as it does just before it would break. I believe this is the animation they refer to.

Comment: @Jasarien that makes sense, but if that's the case the choice of words is rather poor.

Comment: It's a wiki, you could always edit it :)

Answer (score 2):

With the "[Lost Art of the Blacksmith](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/1020)" mod, you can build your own lockpicks at any forge!

Answer (score 1):

You can get a free 30 lockpicks by going to dawn star, every 48 hours go down the path and go to iron breaker mine go to the left and go up near the cliff go into sneak and look around there is a invisible chest with almost 48k in gold, weapons,potions and almost every item in the game and hundreds of full soul gems black to petty. and 30 free lockpicks the best part is it regenerates every 48 hours so you can come back whenever just the first time you have to wait for the khajit caravan then after that it will be there for ever, hope it helps!! :)

(P.s. if you have trouble finding it go to youtube!)

Comment: wow, it sounds awesome but it also sounds like it will spoil my game. thank you for mentioning it.

Answer (score -2):

well I myself am level 15 and after much research I have found that you can find lock pick's on almost every single NPC I have tried pickpocketing them for the "laid to rest" quest given in one of the major town's yet my sneak and thief skill are not yet high enough so the best thing I would suggest would to go to the thief's guild located in the sewer system under Riften and meeting the leader when you ask what she has to sell she carries 27 or more lock picks so I suggest making the trip to get those picks.